# Can't start backup

Tags: adb, backup, 8.0-oreo, nokia-8

I'm trying to backup using `adb backup org.mozilla.firefox` on a Nokia 8 (with Android 8.0).

I get the screen where it asks for a password. There are two texts at the bottom "Cancel" and "Backup my Data". They look identical (i.e. it looks as if I can click either) but nothing happens when I press "Backup my Data". What is going on?

I also tried to enter a password but that doesn't help.

Same effect with `adb backup -apk org.mozilla.firefox`: in both cases, only an empty `backup.ab` file is created. To be sure, I've also included the `-f` option to explicitly specify an output file name – same effect, the file stays empty.

adb version 1.0.39.

Comment: Not sure if it's mandatory, but didn't you miss the `-f <filename>` parameter to tell ADB where to store the backup to?

Comment: Without that, it defaults to `backup.ab`. I can see that an empty file is created. Just to be safe, I also tried with the parameter. Same effect.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron! Just wanted to be sure, as you mentioned neither (even not the empty file). Wouldn't be the first time some device came with a strange ADB daemon. In my case with one device (no longer in use), `adb backup` worked fine but `adb restore` did nothing. So it could be a faulty ADB daemon as well. Have you tried with other apps? It might well be Firefox having backup disabled (`ALLOW_BACKUP:FALSE`). Otherwise, while waiting for answers here, I'd suggest you try contacting Nokia's customer service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mozilla disabled backups [back in 2015](https://wh0.github.io/2015/11/10/fennec.html), documented [in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190375).

Of course this causes a lot of trouble for people trying to get access to their own data.